# php regex for last number before file extension

Tags: php, regex, filenames, filepath

Anyone know how to use preg_match to get last digit given this:

```
images/listings/listings_id_15_4.png
```

or

```
images/listings/listings_id_15_4.jpg
```

The extension may be different, I only need to find the last digit before the '**.**' 
From both of those strings I would just need the '4'

Comment: You want the last digit, right? For instance, if the file name is `images/listings/listings_id_15_423.jpg`, you want `3`?

Comment: Can filename be: `listings_id_45_abc.jpg` also?

Comment: no, filename will only be in one of the formats above but numbers or file extensions could be different

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `$` for that, that means [at the end of string]

You start with the part that gets the extention:

```
\.[a-zA-Z]$ // this will match '.png' and '.jpg'
// Or alternatively
\.\w{2,4}$ // this will match '.png' and '.jpg', 2 till 4 chars long
```

Then you want to get the number in front of it, so expand it from the back:

```
([0-9]+)\.[a-zA-Z]+$ // this will also select the number in front of it
```

Now also select the rest, without putting it in a group (same goes for extention):

```
.*?([0-9]+)\.[a-zA-Z]+$ // this will select the whole thing, but only the number you want is in a group
```

With that regex, you can use the group in your code with something like `\\1` or `$1`

Comment: maybe my syntax is wrong but I'm using preg_match('.*?([0-9]+)\.[a-zA-Z]+$', $img_path, $match) and getting Warning: preg_match(): No ending delimiter '.'

Comment: you need to wrap it in limiters, like this: `preg_replace("/REGEX_HERE/", "\\1", $string);` The error you get is because a delimiter has to be a non alphabetic character, in this case a dot. That means you have to end it with a dot.

Comment: It's common practice to use the `/` as delimiter because a lot of programming languages use that, for consistancy. See the post by SQB -> slashes as delimiter :)

Answer (score 0):

```
/\d(?=\.\w+$)/
```

This matches a digit, that is followed by a dot and one or more word characters (which is what I figure an extension to be).
Add a `+` after the `\d` if you want a full number instead of a single digit.

Comment: shouldn't `(?=\.\w+)` be `(?:\.\w+)`? He doesnt want the group, but the int in front of it...

Comment: @Martijn No, I meant to use lookahead. We're selecting a digit such that we can look ahead and see a string-ending extension. But your comment made me realise I needed to include the `$` in the lookahead, so thanks.